# How Vim saves files when typing :w

Tags: neovim

How vim saves files when typing `:w` in normal mode ? I have the feeling there is something different happening in comparison with other IDEs / Editors.

I ask this because I had issues when developing a frontend app using Storybook (nodejs) => this one freezes when saving a file in vim, and not in other IDEs / Editor.

This makes me think there must be something different with Vim when performing some operations like saving a file.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As it stands, your question *looks* like it's asking the very broad question "How is vim different"—underneath, however, it looks you're *really* asking the much more specific "How does vim save files, and why could that cause problems with Storybook/nodejs?" Please [edit] to clarify, and note that the former question is too broad in scope, while the latter is a good question. If anyone finds a previous question about how vim writes files (which it does oddly, to be fair), please link it here.

Comment: `:h backup-table` `set nowb` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when saving,

> Vim deletes the file and replaces it with a new one with the same attributes, meaning that the previous pointer is no longer valid.

Setting this in vim seems to fix the issue :

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```